# What is wrong with this Entity Framework code? (add some entity)

Tags: c#, entity-framework

```
public class Calendar
{
    DatabaseContext db = new DatabaseContext();

    public List<Day> GetDays()
    {
        User user = User(Session["user"]);
        return user.Days.ToList();
    }

    public void AddDay()
    {
        User user = User(Session["user"]);
        var day = new Day { Date = DateTime.Now, UserID = user.UserID };
        db.Days.Add(day);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

I call `GetDays` method first and it returns a list with Count = 3.

Then I call `AddDay` method and then I call `GetDays` method again and count is still 3!

Please help me. What's wrong?

Comment: You've got to refesh your session after the Add - it's in the database but not session.

Comment: Because `Session["user"]` is not updated when you call `AddDay`.